# How can I get the date of the last transaction from the blockchain.info API?

Tags: api, blockchain.info

Is there a way to request the date of last transaction via API? I run a request to see balance of my addresses and need to request the date of the last transaction, how would I do that?

Comment: Hey, I assume that you are using the blockchain.info api, and thus edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ambiguous question as we don't know what your environment is.
If you are using bitcoind, a call to `gettransaction` will give you a time field which is when the transaction has been seen.

Perhaps if you elaborate a bit more we would be able to answer the question more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the address API i.e.

`https://blockchain.info/address/$hash_160?format=json` you will get a list of transactions.

They all have a time attribute which is the time in unix format. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 0):

import requests
import time

def check_address_last_transaction_dates(filename):
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
address_list = [line.strip() for line in file]

```
for address in address_list:
    url = f"https://blockchain.info/address/{address}?format=json"
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()

        if "txs" in data:
            # Find the most recent transaction in the list of transactions
            transactions = data["txs"]
            if transactions:
                most_recent_tx = max(transactions, key=lambda x: x["time"])
                last_tx_date = most_recent_tx["time"]
                last_tx_date_formatted = format_timestamp_to_month_year(last_tx_date)
                print(f"Address: {address}, Last Transaction Date: {last_tx_date_formatted}\n")
            else:
                print(f"Address: {address}, No last transaction data available\n")
        else:
            print(f"Address: {address}, No transaction data available\n")
    else:
        print(f"Address: {address}, Error fetching data\n")
    
    # Introduce a 1-second delay between checking addresses
    time.sleep(1)
```

def format_timestamp_to_month_year(timestamp):
# Convert UNIX timestamp to month/year format
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)
return date.strftime("%B %Y")

## Specify the filename containing the list of Bitcoin addresses

filename = "btc500.txt"

check_address_last_transaction_dates(filename)

with this code you can check last transaction date/year only no other information.....replace your btc address list file with btc500.txt